# Finding coordinate of maximum value in list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, max, nested-loops

I am tasked with finding the exact coordinate of a maximum value in a list of lists in python. This list of lists is referred to as a grid to emulate topographical coordinates.
Here is the grid, along with my code to find the maximum:

```
grid = [[15, 16, 18, 19, 12, 11],
        [13, 19, 23, 21, 16, 12],
        [12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 10],
        [10, 14, 16, 13, 9, 6]]
maxi = 0
for i in grid:
    for j in i:
        if j > maxi:
            maxi = j
```

This code finds the maximum, however I am stuck on finding the coordinates. The output should be:
global max: (1,2) 23  
Because the maximum (23) is on the First row, and on the second column.
I have tried using index and find but they do not work or take my value as an input. Any tips or help are appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look up the `enumerate()` function.

Comment: I take it this is some kind of homework and aren't allowed to use numpy?

Comment: Yeah it's more of an exercise and I can't use numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin function [enumerate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate).

Update your code to this:

```
grid = [[15, 16, 18, 19, 12, 11],
        [13, 19, 23, 21, 16, 12],
        [12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 10],
        [10, 14, 16, 13, 9, 6]]
        
maxi = -float('inf')
maxCoord = None
for i, row in enumerate(grid):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        if col > maxi:
            maxi = col
            maxCoord = (i, j)
            
print(maxCoord, maxi) #(1, 2) 23
```

Comment: Nitpick: If your list of lists is comprised entirely of negative numbers, `maxCoord` will never change from None. Either set `maxi = -np.inf; maxCoord = None`, or `maxi = grid[0][0]; maxCoord = (0, 0)`.

Comment: That's a good point. Updated the answer to account for that.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I was not too familiar with enumerate. I was just wondering, what is the purpose of the -float('inf') exactly?

Comment: @FranPY3 No problem! Make sure to mark the answer as right if it helped you.
So, ```-float('inf')``` just means negative infinity. I changed the starting value of ```maxi``` to  ```-float('inf')``` because if we start it with ```0```, in case your ```grid``` is made up of negative values only, ```maxi``` the if statement ```if col > maxi``` would never be true, and we would get the wrong output. But if you know your ```grid``` will never have negative values, you can keep ```maxi``` start with ```0```.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerate` could be an option, as it was already proposed. If you want to keep your original function to find the max value, you can call its coordinates using:

```
for sublist in grid:
  if maxi in sublist:
    print(grid.index(sublist), sublist.index(maxi))
```